# Is there a way to read an object's contents (file_get_contents) and get the object metadata using just one read in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Currently, I'm using PHP to fetch an object's custom metadata from Google Cloud Storage using something like this:

```
$meta_data_array = $storage->bucket('bucket_name')->object('objectname.html')->info()['metadata'];
```

And, then I fetch the contents using this:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('gs://bucket_name/objectname.html');
```

Is there a way to combine both into a single PHP database read like this?

```
$object = $storage->bucket('bucket_name')->object('objectname.html');
$meta_data_array = $object->info()['metadata'];
$contents = $object->downloadContents();
//                   ^^^ similar to downloadToFile($destination)
```

I haven't found anything in my doc searches. But it seems that something like this could exist and maybe I just don't know where to look. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageObject::downloadAsString()`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.135.0/storage/storageobject?method=downloadAsString).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but you can 'read' your object like this in **version 1.39**:

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient([
  //your configs
]);
$storage->registerStreamWrapper();
$contents = file_get_contents('gs://'.{{your_bucket}}.'/'.{{$fileName}});
```